# ps and top show a different command name then what pkill and pgrep sees

Tags: linux, process, kill, ps

Often times I want to kill process that I believe has changed its command name ([I think through `setproctitle()` or something similar](http://stupefydeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/10/linux-change-process-name.html)).

Apparent `pkill`, `pgrep`, and friends do not read the new command names (ie ruby process renames its command, pkill still sees it as `ruby` and not `delayed_job`).

However `ps` and `h?top` do.

Is my only resort greping/awking `ps` to kill these kinds of processes or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ps -f`, `pgrep -f` and `pkill -f`.

From the respective man pages:

```
ps -f

Do full-format listing. This option can be combined with many
other UNIX-style options to add additional columns. It also
causes the command arguments to be printed.
```

-

```
pgrep/pkill -f, --full

The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.
When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```